# What is wrong with the default installation of Qt6 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6

I am trying to install Qt 6.4, the online version, on Ubuntu 22.04.
The installation was apparently smooth; I used the default options.
However, when attempting to create a desktop project, I receive the message

```
/opt/Qt/Tools/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47: warning: Found package configuration file: /opt/Qt/6.4.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Gui/Qt6GuiConfig.cmake but it set Qt6Gui_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6Gui" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package: Qt6Gui could not be found because dependency WrapOpenGL could not be found.
```

Did I wrong something? How can I continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the OpenGL development packages like the following.

```
$ sudo apt install libglx-dev
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but that was still helpful. Seems like `libgl1-mesa-dev` is also required.

Answer (score 6):

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626921/michael) suggested that both of these packages are needed: `libglx-dev` and `libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Run this in your terminal to install them:

```
sudo apt install libglx-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
```